# Elasticsearch and Kibana, thousands of documents created I don't know why and connections increasing

Tags: docker, elasticsearch, kibana

I'm actually testing Elasticsearch and Kibana (last versions) with the official Docker images. Everything is up and running and I have indexed only one document. The problem is when I take a look to the monitoring section in Kibana, apparently there is thousands of documents (each seconds dozen are created) and Kibana connections keep increasing (1972 on the screen capture). All these documents are logs? Why there is so many and what about these connections? I'm actually a bit scaried to use it in production since I don't find any information about it.

[screen capture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HiVvn.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

They are data indexes for X-Pack monitoring. Click on the Indices link and check the box for "Show system indices" to view them. Also, see https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/x-pack/current/xpack-monitoring.html for more information.

The Docker image for Kibana actually has an environment variable to disable monitoring named `XPACK_MONITORING_ENABLED`. You can set this to `false` when starting the Kibana container using `-e XPACK_MONITORING_ENABLED=false`. See https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/kibana/6.1/_configuring_kibana_on_docker.html.

Though, you should note that the environment variable is actually broken at the moment and you need to also disable `xpack.monitoring.ui.container.elasticsearch.enabled` in the `kibana.yml`. See https://github.com/elastic/kibana/issues/14967.